# Use longer ids for AWS EC2/EBS resources

Tags: java, maven, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, instance

I need to setup my machines with longer instance IDs like described in:

https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/#longer-ids

I am currently using maven with the br.com.ingenieux beanstalk-maven-plugin (version 1.5) plugin to deploy a java tomcat8 project. I already checked the documentation for  settings to do so:

http://beanstalker.ingenieux.com.br/beanstalk-maven-plugin/create-environment-mojo.html#optionSettings.

But I could not find any solution to deploy automatically my project with longer instance IDs.

Does anyone know how to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't control the instance IDs, Amazon does. You simply have to opt in for them to create longer IDs for any new instances you create. Unless you rely on software which for some reason relies on the length of instance IDs (for example saving them into a `VARCHAR(<something less than 17>)` column) you should be fine to opt in. At work we've done a region by region opt-in in the last couple weeks, and haven't had any problems.